# Using BOTH xib and .m files to configure autolayout constraints

Tags: ios

My question is a general one, and for good reason because this scenario is widely applicable.

It would be extremely convenient to specify SOME auto layout constraints in the .xib file, but not all.  At this stage, it would be an ambiguous layout that would not compile.

Then in the .m file, one could configure the rest of the auto layout constraints using all of the programmatic tools that are available (for example, checking screen size, or device orientation, or device type, etc.).

Is this possible?

I am not asking for a solution to a particular problem, I am trying to explore a technique that would make configuring view layouts extremely efficient: catching the best of the xib layout methodology and the best of the .m programmatic layout methodology simultaneously.  Any one have any experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: You can compile your app with ambiguous, insufficient or even conflicting constraints.  At run time you will get warnings and/or incorrect layout if you haven't corrected the constraints programatically.  Generally I try to set all constraints through IB and modify them at run time if required

Answer (score 0):

you can make your xib constraints a placeholder so that they won't get compiled at runtime and you can create new ones in code; Or, you can deactive your xib constraints and set active=true on them when needed.

Comment: ahh, I see, the little placeholder checkbox on the size inspector, which will "remove at build time."  Is it then as simple as putting in the actual constraint in code?  it would make sense, since the viewDidLoad method is called after the xib has been set up.  Thank you.